# How to have vnoremap call function once?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

I'm trying to write a function + map that works on a visual selection. My function just prints out the marks right now:

```
let g:count = 0
function! s:plink(...) abort
    let g:count = g:count + 1
    echomsg printf("%d %s %d %s %d", g:count, a:1, line(a:1), a:2, line(a:2))
endfunction
vnoremap <Leader>r :call <SID>plink("'<", "'>")<CR>
```

I was surprised to find out that my function is being called once per line when I invoke it as `shift-V`, select lines, `\r`:

```
1 '< 80 '> 84
2 '< 80 '> 84
3 '< 80 '> 84
4 '< 80 '> 84
5 '< 80 '> 84
```

How do I make this snippet call my code only once when I invoke it?

Comment: Heya, I've undeleted your question, as deleting it also deleted the answer. See [this meta post](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1471/51).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start an ex-command (`:`) from visual mode, Vim automatically prepends `'<,'>` to the command.

Function calls can accept ranges, of which the above is an example: when given them, they are called once for each line.

One fix is to get rid of the range when the function is called:

```
xnoremap <Leader>r :<C-u>call ...
```

(Note that I’ve switched to `xnoremap` to only map in visual mode—`vnoremap` includes select mode, which generally is undesirable.)

---

The alternative is to declare the function with the range attribute (see `:help func-range`).

Then the mapping is unchanged, but the declaration must take two arguments (`a:firstline` and `a:lastline`).